# Basemap m.fillcontinents() suppresses points on plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, matplotlib-basemap

I'd like to change the colour of the land on a map, but doing so overrides any markers I may have on land. The m.fillcontinents() command suppresses any points of interest plotted. How do I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the problem was related to the zorder settings, so somethng like:

```
m.scatter(x, y, zorder=2)
m.fillcontinents(color='#997766', lake_color='#99ffff', zorder=1)
```

where setting the symbols to a higher priority (zorder=2) than the fillcontinents (zorder=1) seemed to resolve the issue.